# Probability binomial distribution and Poisson distribution

Tags: binomial-coefficients

It is found that 5% of screws in a factory are found to be defective. Use the Poisson theorum and the binomial theorum to compute the probability that two or more are found to be defective if a sample of 20 screws is tested.

Can anyone pleasssssse help me with this I've been at it for ages, I'm ok at the binomial but hard to know what to put into formula but really dnt get the Poisson theorum??? Thanks so much :)

How to start binomial?

Answer (score 0):

The [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Derivation_of_Poisson_distribution_.E2.80.94_The_law_of_rare_events) here is 
$$
B(n,p)\simeq Poisson (np).
$$
where the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Derivation_of_Poisson_distribution_.E2.80.94_The_law_of_rare_events) is such as
$$
P(N=k) = \exp(-np)\frac{(np)^k}{k!}
$$
($\exp$ is the exponential).

Here $n=20, p = 0.05$ so $np=1$.

Then with $N$ being the number of defective screws: $$
P(N\ge 2) = 1 - P(N=0) - P(N=1) \simeq 1- \frac{\exp (-1)}{0!}
- \frac{\exp (-1)}{1!} \simeq 0.26
$$

Comment: He is also asking for Binomial which is computable. Give him guidance on that too!!

Comment: That is the Poisson way? What does exp stand for?? Thank u very much for your response

Comment: i tried to clarify.

Comment: Satish what is the landa in thus case using the landa Poisson formula?

Comment: it is $\lambda = np$